# Index a subdirectory of DocumentRoot Apache

Tags: apache, indexing

I've the DocumentRoot with the Options +Indexes enabled. However, I cannot find via browser the subdirs of the DocumentRoot.
How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe they don't have the read and execute permission flag set?

Try `chmod ug+rx filename` and make sure the subdirs belong to the apache user.

Comment: Well, yes, I was a permission problem. They was 700 I don't know why :D Sometimes, when you're stuck in a problem, it's just a matter of point of view.
Thanks :)